# Description of classes in $H^2(K,GL_n)$

Tags: galois-cohomology

Let $K$ be a field, we know elements in $H^2(K,\mathbb{G}_m)=\mathrm{Br}(K)$ can be represented by division algebras over $K$.

Do we have some description of elements in $H^2(K,GL_n)$ for $n>1$? They should give elements in $\mathrm{Br}(K)$ via taking determinant.

Comment: What is $H^2(K,GL_n)$ for you?

Comment: There is no such thing. Nonabelian cohomology only goes up to $H^1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Right, sorry I asked as stupid question...but for $\mathbb{G}_m$, cohomology class in $H^2(K,\mathbb{G}_m)$ represents a gerbe, which is a stack locally isomorphic to $B\mathbb{G}_m$, do we have similar notion for stacks locally isomorphic to $BGL_n$?

Comment: Giraud worked out a theory of non-abelian $H^2$ in his book, which is possibly what you are after.

Comment: @Qixiao: stacks locally isomorphic to $BG$ are classified by $H^1(-, \text{Aut}(BG))$ where $\text{Aut}(BG)$ is a $2$-group with $\pi_0$ given by $\text{Out}(G)$ and $\pi_1$ given by $Z(G)$. This is cohomology but with coefficients in a $2$-group rather than a group, and calling it nonabelian $H^2$ is in my opinion highly misleading. Among other things, it does not specialize to abelian $H^2$ when $G$ is abelian: $H^2(-, A)$ for $A$ abelian is given by *Picard* stacks (symmetric monoidal grouplike stacks) locally isomorphic to $BA$.

Comment: Nonabelian $H^2$ in the Galois-cohomological  setting was developed by Springer.  See [my preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.07366)  for references and definitions.